# How to exclude from recents an exported activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-recents

I have an app with an exported activity that can be invoked from other apps (Specifically the sharing action - `android.intent.action.SEND`)

**How can an exported activity be excluded from recents?**

I don't see a way to set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` flag, because it is invoked from the outside.

The reason I want to do this is because this intent becomes the last one in my activity stack, thus when clicking on the recents, a file is being re-shared instead of the main activity to pop up.

*Note*: `android:launchMode="singleTask"` solves the problem in a specific case, only where another activity is on top. BUT, this isn't an option because it disrupts the user task flow and doesn't work if there is no other app's activity at the root.

Comment: Try adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to the `<activity>` element of that Activity in the manifest.

Comment: How simple. Missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the [android:excludeFromRecents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) attirbute to your `<activity>` element in the manifest with a value of true:

```
<activity
    android:name="XYZ"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```