# way to exit from the app in android

Tags: android

I have a HomeActivity (for show splash screen in 3 seconds) , then automatically redirect to LoginActivity (for check users information for login).
In LoginActivity I have a exit button for exit the app, with below code

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         finish();
         android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.  myPid());
         System.exit(0);
```

I used the same code in onDestroy() again.
But , when I try to exit from the app , Program is firmly closed. but remains in memory (in background app list ). How can I solve it?

Comment: Android kill process own its own, it is not a good practice to kill Processes on your own. `finish()` is the best way to exit from an activity

Comment: ok, I used Finish(); alone , Does not work. I used Finish() with System.exit(0), Does not work. I tried many ways, I did not answer.

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202259/how-to-exclude-from-recents-an-exported-activity

Comment: finish() finishes an activity, if your app contains multiple activity, you need to close all of them

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to call:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

because android will handle processes automatically.
Also exclude your app from recent isn't a correct behavior.

By the way you can put under your "exit" activity tag in manifest:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

And it will not appear in recent apps when the app is closed

**EDIT**

If it doesn't work in Android 5.0 it was a reported bug, so add taskAffinity property and use autoRemoveFromRecents:

```
android:taskAffinity=".YourExitActivity"
android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
```

Then in your `onPause()` you can check the sdk version to use `finishAndRemoveTask`:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    finishAndRemoveTask();
} else {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: excuse me , your Idea dose not work. my problem is still there.

Comment: thanks, my problem was solved. I used 'android:excludeFromRecents="true" ' in the first activity tag ( in manifest).

Comment: excuse me , my reputation is lower than 15.

Answer (score 0):

finish() is enough.

If the app still remains in memory after call finish(), it may be Memory leak in your app.

Answer (score 0):

While mentioning  tag in manifest we can keep

```
 `android:`noHistory=true
```

so that mentioned activity wont be in back stack.

For example:

```
<activity
            android:name="Splash_Activity"
            android:label="Splash"
            android:noHistory="true" />
```

You can call just `finish()` to close activity.